# Find all combinations with conditions to achieve a given sum in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have numbers from 1 to 59, and their frequency as well.
There are 4 pririotes:

1. Any two numbers sum to 60, cannot exceed their frequency
2. Any three numbers sum to 60, cannot exceed their frequency
3. Any four numbers sum to 60, cannot exceed their frequency
4. Any five numbers sum to 60, cannot exceed their frequency

Can VBA solve this problem? Can anyone help? Thanks~

Below is the raw data:

> - Numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
>     46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59  -Frequency: 866 356 292 229
>     145 125 100 100 74 69 57 60 54 25 35 32 25 28 20 33 18 17 21 19 21 23
>     19 21 9 13 9 13 11 9 13 7 10 14 10 17 3 4 6 5 5 8 9 10 5 6 5 4 2 5 6 5
>     3 3 3

Comment: `1. 30+30 ; 2. 20+20+20 ; 3. 15+15+15+15 ; 4. 12+12+12+12+12` Here you have solution.

Comment: Sorry I might not explain well. Actually I need to know in total how many combinations to satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

[image]

Code:

```
Sub FindSeries()

Dim StartRng As Range
Dim EndRng As Range
Dim Answer As Long
Dim TestTotal As Long

Answer = Range("B1") '<<< CHANGE

Set StartRng = Range("A1")
Set EndRng = StartRng
Do Until False
    TestTotal = Application.Sum(Range(StartRng, EndRng))
    If TestTotal = Answer Then
        Range(StartRng, EndRng).Select
        Exit Do
    ElseIf TestTotal > Answer Then
        Set StartRng = StartRng(2, 1)
        Set EndRng = StartRng
    Else
        Set EndRng = EndRng(2, 1)
        If EndRng.Value = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "No series found"
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```